# Selecting unit if ray intersects

Tags: unity

Again some problems with my RTS base:

I have worked on the script that should select the unit, if its clicked.
In this case, I check if the raycast hit's the object and checks, if it has a selectable child, which is basically a projector for a circle on the ground. This should be toggled on.

[image]

You can see, how the clored ray intersects with the unit but it doesn't show the expected debug message.

Here's my full code that handles the mouse interactions:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Mouse : MonoBehaviour {

    RaycastHit hit;

    public static GameObject CurrentUnit;

    private static Vector3 mouseDownPoint;

    void Awake()
    {
        mouseDownPoint = Vector3.zero;
    }

    public GameObject Target; 

    private float raycastLength = 1000; // Mathf.Infinity;
    void Update () {

        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, raycastLength)) { 
            if (Input.GetMouseButton(1))
            {
                mouseDownPoint = hit.point;
            }
            if (hit.collider.name == "Terrain")
            {
                if (Input.GetMouseButton(1)) // wenn rechtslick -> ziel instanziieren
                {
                    GameObject TargetObj = Instantiate(Target, hit.point, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
                    TargetObj.name = "Target Instance";
                }
                else if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0) && CheckLeftClick(mouseDownPoint))

                    DeselectIfSelected();
                //Terrain click end
            }
            else {
                if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0) && CheckLeftClick(mouseDownPoint))
                {
                    //does the ray hit a unit with selection child?
                    if (hit.collider.transform.FindChild("Selection"))
                    {
                        //unit found
                        Debug.Log("Unit found");

                        if (CurrentUnit != hit.collider.gameObject)
                        {
                            //enable the selection child
                            GameObject SelectedObj = hit.collider.transform.FindChild("Selection").gameObject;
                            SelectedObj.SetActive(true);
                            if (CurrentUnit != null)
                                CurrentUnit.transform.FindChild("Selection").gameObject.SetActive(false);
                            //replace selection
                            CurrentUnit = hit.collider.gameObject;


                        }
                    } else
                    {
                        //if not a unit
                        DeselectIfSelected();
                    }
                }
            }
            } else {
                if(Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0) && CheckLeftClick(mouseDownPoint))
                {
                    DeselectIfSelected();
                }
            }

        Debug.DrawRay(ray.origin, ray.direction * raycastLength, Color.yellow); // ray to position

    }

    #region Helper 

    //check, if mouse is clicked

    public bool CheckLeftClick(Vector3 hitPoint)
    {
        float clickZone = 0.8f;
        if (
         (mouseDownPoint.x < hitPoint.x + clickZone && mouseDownPoint.x > hitPoint.x - clickZone) &&
         (mouseDownPoint.y < hitPoint.y + clickZone && mouseDownPoint.y > hitPoint.y - clickZone) &&
         (mouseDownPoint.z < hitPoint.z + clickZone && mouseDownPoint.z > hitPoint.z - clickZone))
            return true;
            else return false;
    }


    public static void DeselectIfSelected()
    {
        if (CurrentUnit != null) {
            CurrentUnit.transform.FindChild("Selection").gameObject.SetActive(false);
            CurrentUnit = null;
        }
    }
    #endregion

}
```

I'd be very happy, if someone could help with that problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have "Selection" GO disabled by default, do you have any script that enables it? also make sure it has Collider.

Comment: Wow, I feel so stupid right now :D Tank you, i forgot the collider

Comment: haha glad i helped!